# Unable to render a plugin template

Tags: plugin-development, templating, custom-fieldtype

Creating a plugin that contains a custom field. I need to have some custom html for the settings of the field. I have the following in my field class:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate("src/templates/settings.html", [
        'field' => $this,
    ]);
}
```

I have a "settings.html" in "src/templates".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/updating-plugins.md#rendering-templates) (or [this](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/templates.html)) about how to render plugin templates. It's all well explained there . You don't need to define `src/templates` but your plugin handle

```
`plugin-handle/settings.html`
```